# Java Recursively delete the content in the format

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion

I use recursion to remove the unnecessary characters in a text.

EX : 
source ="This is demo java remove string"

regex ="This,is,java"

result ="demo remove string"

I had difficulty not provide conditions when the program stops recursive function.If there is any way to work more efficiently using recursive please tell me

```
public class NewClass2 {

    static String regexs[] = {"This","is", "java"};

    private static String getRecursive(String source, int level) {

        String content = "";

        if (level > regexs.length - 1) {
            return "";
        }

        level++;

        for (String regex : regexs) {
            content = source.replaceAll(regex, "");

            if (!content.equals("")) {
                content = getRecursive(content, level);
            }
        }
        return content;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = getRecursive("This is demo java remove string", 0);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have to use recursion?

Comment: in this set up, you dont really need to recurse. you can do it easily inside your for loop

Comment: you either use a for loop or a recursive function, you don't need booth, no need for second IF statement, you have one at the start of the function (janos answer)

Comment: Thanks all very much for the suggestion and the statement, they worked perfectly,I've learned a lot

Comment: @janos I think wants to perform can just use recursion,I do not know there are other possible methods of implementation. So it's great that I can see your methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recursive method is...all wrong.

- You shouldn't use a loop there.
- When `level > regexs.length - 1`, you should return `source`, not `""`

The method cleaned up becomes a lot simpler:

```
private static String getRecursive(String source, int level) {
    if (level >= regexs.length) {
        return source;
    }
    return getRecursive(source.replaceAll(regexs[level], ""), level + 1);
}
```

However, this still doesn't give exactly what you asked for.
It gives "  demo  remove string" instead of "demo remove string",
because the values in `regexs` don't contain spaces, so the spaces between words are not removed. To work around that, you could append `"\\s*"` to the patterns, for example:

```
    return getRecursive(source.replaceAll(regexs[level] + "\\s*", ""), level + 1);
```

Comment: Very full statement, it helped me not be worried contain spaces

Comment: When using recursion to handle more data would be very good if applied executor. I have difficulty with the check when the work is completed, I look forward to your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512762/how-is-an-executor-termination-recursion-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have to use recursion. Let's assume you have to use recursion. Let's assume you have to use recursion... ;)

I hate arrays in java. They are not necessary:

```
Queue regexs = new LinkedList<String>();
regexs.add("This");
regexs.add("is");
regexs.add("Java");

private static String getRecursive(String someSource, Queue regs) {
    if (regs.size() != 0) return getRecursive(someSource.replaceAll(regs.poll(), ""), regs);
    else return someSource;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue regsCopy = new LinkedList(regexs); // we make a copy of the original queue list so that we can use it again in the future. Otherwise the list will be empty after just one use of the getRecursive method.
    System.out.println(getRecusive("This is demo java removing string", regsCopy));
}
```

Comment: *Let's assume that you have to use recursion. Let's assume that you have to use recursion...* -> This is iteration, not recursion. :P

Comment: Iteration transverses a list which could or could not be duplicates. Recursion is repetition. Recursion that programmers look to do is degenerate recursion so that it ends naturally. :P

Comment: Iteration starts a step, then it completes the step, then it starts the next step. Recursion starts a step, then asks itself for the result of a substep, which asks itself for the result of a substep, which asks itself for the result of a substep, which... **3!** -> **2!** -> **1!** -> **0!**

Comment: Agree to disagree. Now we shall eat cake (though we must debate if the cake is a lie or not).

Comment: As long as I get to hold the gun, I am happy with eating either real or lied cake.

Comment: Thank you both.@brimborium I think the program should not pay much attention to the data in the array.Then the data transmission and read **regexs[]=JTextArea.getText().split("\n")** makes it easy to transfer data to an array list

Answer (score 3):

do you have to use recursion? a simpler approach would be

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("This|is|java");
Matcher m = p.matcher("This is demo java remove string");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

also, if you just have your for loop as the following

```
for (String regex : regexs) {
            source= source.replaceAll(regex, "");
            }

System.out.println(source);

return source;
```

you dont need to recurse.

Comment: Thank you AbtPst.Code 1 perfect but code 2 : is incorrect.It will only replace the last character.

Comment: I don't understand 2 works now.But your code 2 is true when using recursion (janos answered).With math as my if not find a way to replace the use of recursion is a great method. I think so